# Counting referenced records by trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-server-2012

I've discovered a new problem: I have a two tables, **Classes** and **Students**. **Students** references to **Classes** by *[ClassID]* column. **Classes** have column named *[Count]*, which storing count of referencing students and I'm trying update it via **AFTER INSERT,DELETE** trigger on **Students** table.
I wrote a simple **CALC_COUNT** procedure like that:

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CALC_COUNT]
    @classid INT
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE classes SET [Count] = (SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM students WHERE [ClassID] = @classid);
END

RETURN 0
```

---

and use it inside trigger

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER [MONITOR_STUDENTS_SCHEMA_TRIGGER]
    ON [dbo].[students]
    AFTER DELETE, INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[classes] 
        SET studentsschemarev +=1  FROM inserted; 
        CALC_COUNT(SELECT [ClassID] FROM inserted UNION SELECT [ClassID] FROM deleted); 
        UPDATE [dbo].[stats] SET students_schema_rev += 1;
    END
```

---

**But it not works. 
I think, I need a way to execute procedure for each row in SELECT statement of trigger, but I don't know how.**

SQL Server 2012 LocalDB, compatibility mode with SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your stored proc.

Update your trigger to be

```
update classes
set 
   count = StudentCount,
   schemarevcount += 1
from
    classes 
        inner join
    (select * from inserted union select * from deleted) students
        on classes.classid=students.classid
        inner join 
    (select classid, count(*) as StudentCount from students group by classid) counts
        on students.classid = counts.classid
```

in place of the update and the call to calc_count

An english translation...

- Update classes (set the revision and the count)
- where the class is changed in the students table
- where that class is in the set of counts of students per class

Comment: >on classes.studentid=students.classid  

//no, students have [ClassID], but classes doesn't have [StudentID]. Crossed many2many isn't good.

Comment: My bad - should be classes.classid

Comment: First, Class have ID, not ClassID. ClassID have Students. Second - who are "counts"?
Count of students storing into Classes record.

Comment: 1. Change class.classid to class.id where applicable
2. "counts" is the subquery calculation of the student count per class

Comment: My fragile brain will explode after I will try understand this, but thanks, testing now.

Comment: Explanation added - may help, might not :)

Comment: No, there is no problem. 
First time I see declaring "sets" like counts and StudentCount on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main reason your trigger is not fired, is because you are doing an UPDATE where your trigger is going of on a INSERT and DELETE.

Yes, an UPDATE is a DELETE and INSERT, but you have to put it in your footprint :

```
AFTER DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
```

instead of

```
AFTER DELETE, INSERT
```

Next, in the trigger itself you only have the internal conceptual tables called inserted and deleted, which combined give you the update. The old part is in the deleted table, the new part is in the inserted table.

Why you want to execute record by record by the way? Doing it with a complete resultset is much faster!